# Python slicing and negative stride - why are these examples apparently contradictory?

Tags: python, slice

I've read a bunch of answers here about combining slicing with negative strides, but the following issue still confuses me. In several places, I've seen the diagram below used to illustrate how slice notation works (referring to gaps, rather than entries):

```
 +---+---+---+---+
 | T | e | s | t |
 +---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4
-4  -3  -2  -1
```

These examples are consistent with the diagram above:

```
>>> "Test"[2:]
'st'

>>> "Test"[-2:]
'st'
```

But

```
>>> "Test"[-2::-1]
'seT'
```

does not seem consistent - if starting at the `-2` divider, and counting backwards, why is the `s` also included in the returned string?

Comment: range(1,3) = 1 to 3 with 3 removed. range(3,1,-1) = 3 to 1 with 1 removed. They are not 'the same range, just flipped'.

Comment: Your starting point is still the left edge of the element to be included. Going forward, it's the left edge of `s`, but also going backward. Try `"Test"[2::-1]` as well.

Comment: This phrase: "...the left edge of the element to be included" definitely helps with visualization. Thanks for the rapid answers all, digesting right now :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mental model you have is thus only useful to *positive* stride values, but it doesn't help when using negative strides. Use the following picture instead:

```
  +---+---+---+---+
  | T | e | s | t |
  +---+---+---+---+
    0   1   2   3   4
-5 -4  -3  -2  -1
```

where you label the indices, **not** the boundaries.

The boundary model is nice, but only for making it easier to forget about the fact that the end index is not included in the resulting value. By just numbering the indices instead and omitting the end index, you can see how both positive and negative strides work.

For the nitty gritty details, take a look at the official documentation for the way Python calculates slices; from the [sequence type notes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#index-22) (note 5):

> `s[i:j:k]`
>   The slice of `s` from `i` to `j` with step `k` is defined as the sequence of items with index `x = i + n*k` such that `0 <= n < (j-i)/k`. In other words, the indices are `i`, `i+k`, `i+2*k`, `i+3*k` and so on, stopping when `j` is reached (but never including `j`). If `i` or `j` is greater than `len(s)`, use `len(s)`. If `i` or `j` are omitted or `None`, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of `k`). Note, `k` cannot be zero. If `k` is `None`, it is treated like `1`.

So, for your negative stride, the values become:

```
i = len(s) - 2 = 2 
j = None = -1 (end for negative strides, *not* len(s) - 1)
k = -1
```

where `j` is the 'end', here -1 as that is the point where you ran out of string in a negative step. Then the indices become:

```
x0 = i + 0*k = 2
x1 = i + 1*k = 1
x2 = i + 2*k = 0
```

giving you 3 indices.

Answer (score 1):

If `"Test"[-2:]` includes `s`, then by the same logic, it'll include `s` in `"Test"[-2::-1]` as the range includes the first position but excludes the second position.

Comment: Ramchandra, this description doesn't match with the 'intuition' provided by the diagram in the question (in which indices refer to spaces between elements, rather that elements themselves), but I think Evert's comment on the original question provides a more intuitive model.